# How to iterate over a list of lists in Sightly?

Tags: aem, sightly

My Sling Model returns a List of Lists of an object I created. (TablegGridDataRow) but I cannot iterate over it. The type of the object is:

```
    List<List<TableGridDataRow>>
```

And I'm doing this to iterate over it.

```
     <sly data-sly-list.row="${tablegrid.bodyNodes}" data-sly-unwrap>
         <tr class="tablegrid__row" data-sly-list.column="${row}">
         ...
```

But I get a NPE when trying to extract the second list.

If instead of a TableGridDataRow I use a String, it works.

Comment: It would be useful if you could post the stack trace.

Answer (score 4):

You can use Sightly tag for iterating the list of lists.
I am posting a code for iterating List>.Here item will have the node of list of list.

```
<div data-sly-use.carouselobj = "com.test.cms.models.MultiItemCarouselModel" data-sly-unwrap >

<header id="myCarousel" >
        <div data-sly-list="${carouselobj.listOLists}">
                 <div data-sly-list-child="${item}">
                      <img src = "${child.imageSrc @ context='uri'}"  />
                                <h2>${child.imageAlt}</h2>
                               <h2>${child.title}</h2>
                          </div>
                   </div>
        </div>
</div>
```

It would be helpful if you upload your Java class.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I used an inner class to solve it in the end and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Default sightly tag was data-sly-list.child corrected, this should work.

```
<div data-sly-use.carouselobj = "com.test.cms.models.MultiItemCarouselModel" data-sly-unwrap >
   <header id="myCarousel" >
   <div data-sly-list="${carouselobj.listOLists}">
      <div data-sly-list.child="${item}">
         <img src = "${child.imageSrc @ context='uri'}"  />
         <h2>${child.imageAlt}</h2>
         <h2>${child.title}</h2>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
</div>
```